# How to Move extraneous files to folder?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
HashSet<string> allowedFiles = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
{
    "file1.dll",
    "file2.dll",
    "file3.exe",
    "file4.ttf"
};

List<FileInfo> unAllowed = files.FindAll(f => !allowedFiles.Contains(f.Name));

if (unAllowed.Count > 0)
{
//messagebox code
if (gtanotclean == DialogResult.OK)
   {
        try
        {
             //here must be moving code
        }
        catch
        {
             //mycatch
        }
     }
}
```

My problem will be this: How to Move extraneous files to folder?
I know what I must use:

```
File.Move(Filename, Folder);
```

But how can i move only these files which prints unallowed list? It must be foreach or smth like this.. Thanks in advance

Comment: where do you want to move it to? c drive or what?

Comment: Directory.CurrentDirectory()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the files you need to move in the `unAllowed` list, so to move them to the current directory, you can simply do this:

```
unAllowed.ForEach(file => file.MoveTo(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), file.Name)));
```

If you prefer, you can do with a normal `foreach`..

```
foreach (var file in unAllowed)
    file.MoveTo(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), file.Name));
```