# C# Move file from bool

Tags: c#, boolean, move

I have this code:

```
bool containsNonAllowedCLEOFiles = directory.EnumerateFiles().Any(file => !allowedCLEOFiles.Contains(file.Name));

if (containsNonAllowedCLEOFiles == true)
{
    DialogResult existsunallowedcleofiles = MessageBox.Show("Extraneous files found! Please remove them", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning); 
    if(existsunallowedcleofiles == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        //move files
    }
    return;
}
```

If extraneous/unallowed files exist, I'm getting this message. But I want to move those files to another directory when I click OK. How can I do it? I want to move not all files, but only extraneous / unallowed.

**P.S** I know that I must use File.Move("file", "directory"); or
something like this, but I don't know how to get that file name.. etc.

Comment: [What was wrong with your other question on the same topic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31491959/how-to-move-extraneous-files-to-folder)

Comment: You have already posted same question few days back and even got answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
foreach (var file in directory.EnumerateFiles().Where(file => !allowedCLEOFiles.Contains(file.Name)) {
    File.Move(file.Name, destination);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well it sounds like you should first find those files, then check whether or not there are any:

```
var invalidFiles = directory.EnumerateFiles()
                            .Where(file => !allowedCLEOFiles.Contains(file.Name));
                            .ToList();
if (invalidFiles.Any())
{
    // ... Prompt user as before ...
    foreach (var invalidFile in invalidFiles)
    {
        File.Move(...);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
var disallowedFiles = directory.EnumerateFiles().Where(file => allowedCLEOFiles.Contains(file.Name)).ToList();

if (disallowedFiles.Any())
{
    DialogResult existsunallowedcleofiles = MessageBox.Show("Extraneous files found! Please remove them", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning); 
    if(existsunallowedcleofiles == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        disallowedFiles.ForEach(file => File.Move(file.Name, "destination"));
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You may use:

```
var filesMatchingPattern = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(DIRECTORY, PATTERN);
```